# Is Devcon conference the best place to learn about Ethereum?

Tags: devcon

What's the benefits of going to Devcon2?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a rather subjective question, but I would say the best place to learn about Ethereum is by reading the [Homestead guide](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/). That's how I've learned most of what I know. The guide is short, concise, and an incredible starting point.

Best of luck!

**Edit 2016/07/29:** Replaced Frontier with Homestead, which is the current release and updated the link.

Comment: Frontier was the first mainnet launch of Ethereum, and Homestead is the current one: http://ethdocs.org